# Is it a sandbox issue? how to fix it? (I am implementing a plugin of apple mail)

Tags: macos, plugins, apple-mail

Maybe this [tutorial](http://eaganj.free.fr/weblog/?post/2009/07/14/Demystifying-Mail.app-Plugins-on-Leopard) is out of date( it was written in 2009),but I cannot find a better one. While following it step by step, I was stuck at Loading a Plugin section. Apple mail failed to load the plugin.

here is a screenshot of Console's information.[image]

Has anybody else tried to follow this tutorial on OS X 10.9 recently?

////////////////////update/////////////////////////

It seems "~/Library/Mail/Bundles/MyPlugin.mailbundle/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/python" needs code signing.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is a sandbox problem: Python Mail plug-ins (and I think *all* plug-ins) cannot read files outside of their container (the `Plugin.mailbundle` directory).

If you followed the instructions on the tutorial page you mention, you are probably building an *alias build* of the plug-in (using `python setup.py py2app -A`), which means that the plug-in will try and access files from the original source location, which is almost always outside of the sandbox (in your case, it's `/Users/greedyint/Desktop`).

Try running without `-A` to make a full build.

Comment: I followed your solution, now apple mail would crash when I launched it. :(   I think the problem is about code signing. However, I just wanna develop a demo, how can I skip code signing, or can I develop it under develop mode or something?(Console information is uploaded to OP).

Comment: I don't code-sign my plug-in. Perhaps you need to turn on _"Allow applications downloaded from: Anywhere"_ in the _Security & Private_ system preferences.

Comment: I've tried to build your project on github and move it to ~/Library/Mail/Bundles. It makes Apple mail crash either, and the error information is same. And the option you mentioned is already turned on.

Comment: On the other, your released version works well... so there must be something wrong when I built your project.

Comment: @GaojinHsu I have to say that I don't build the plug-in on 10.9 because I'm still on 10.8, so perhaps that's the reason. Another might be that I don't use the Python version provided by OS X, but a Python that I installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Comment: Thanks for your reminding, I've tried on 10.8(just using the Python version provided by OS X), and it turns out you are right, everything works perfectly well on 10.8. Maybe we should fix the problem...but now I have to finish the tutorial. Thanks again.